# Reaction of benzene diazonium salts with different compounds

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds, amines

> **1.** $ \ce{ArN2+Cl-}$ gives addition product with $\alpha,\beta$ unsaturated acids, with decarboxylation being integral part of reaction. For example,
>   $$\ce{ArN2+Cl- + Ph-CH=CH-COOH -> Ph-CH=CH-Ar +CO2 + HCl}$$
>
> **2.** With $\ce{SnCl2/HCl, ArN2+Cl-}$ given phenyl hydrazine $\ce{ArNH-NH2.HCl}$

I can not find mechanism of any of these reactions, first reaction seems  similar to Meerwein reaction (without $\ce{Cu^2+}$), but certainly can't follow similar mechanism. Second reaction is completely different from either. What are the reaction mechanisms of each?

Comment: The Meerwein Arylation Reaction (item 1) has been reviewed. It requires copper salts. https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/epdf/10.1002/0471264180.or011.03

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As to your first reaction that does not utilize copper, a reference to the source would be useful. Nonetheless, the Meerwein Arylation Reaction has been [reviewed](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/epdf/10.1002/0471264180.or011.03) in Organic Reactions. The reaction is conducted in the presence of catalytic cuprous ion. Meerwein proposed an aryl cation but a radical mechanism appears plausible. Reduction of the aryldiazonium salt **1** produces aryl radical **2** and cupric ion. Addition of the aryl radical to cinnamic acid **3** to the double bond to give the more stable of two possible radicals, ---namely--- the benzylic radical **4**. This radical is oxidized by cupric ion to produce benzylic cation **5** and the catalyst cuprous ion. Loss of CO<sub>2</sub> forms the stilbene **6**.
[image]

Comment: Is it E-stilbene? Shouldn't be stereospecific ig..

Comment: You mean stereoselective. Probably, that's what I drew.

Comment: Didn't you draw stereospecific product, anyway I got your point (+1). What about second reaction..

Comment: Not much to say. SnCl2 adds electrons to the diazonium salt and HCl provides protons. The resulting phenyldiimide does the same thing. This was how Emil Fischer made phenylhydrazine with KHSO3. See: http://ursula.chem.yale.edu/~chem220/chem220js/STUDYAIDS/history/Fischer/fischer.html and https://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/ed054p295

Comment: As to stereoselective vs. stereospecific, see ths ChemSE site: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/72694/selectivity-in-organic-reactions